# How to install pathogen on Neovim?

Tags: neovim, plugin-pathogen

I've read that pathogen works on nvim, i tried to follow the vim installation process:

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle && \
curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim
```

Changing the .vim/bundle part:

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.local/share/nvim/bundle && \
curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim
```

my init.vim is:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
set guicursor=
set clipboard+=unnamedplus
```

when i launch nvim i get:

```
E117: unknown function: pathogen#infect()
E15: invalid expression: pathogen#infect()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> `mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.local/share/nvim/bundle`

This is wrong for Neovim.  `~/.config/nvim` is the replacement for `~/.vim`.

`mkdir -p ~/.config/nvim/autoload ~/.config/nvim/bundle` is what you should use.

*If* you want to your config to work with both Vim and Neovim, then I would recommend symlinks.

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/
ln -s ~/.vim ~/.config/nvim 
ln -s ~/.vimrc ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
```

`~/.local/share/nvim/init` is also part of `'runtimepath'`, so if you wanted to keep plugins separate from your personal config, that would be an alternate place to put the `bundle` directory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was copying/pasting stuff and I did not changed everything I needed on the commands. However, I will not mark this answer as the solution, because in order to get pathogen you need to put the autoload folder inside ./config/nvim https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/issues/50. Obs: I'm loving neovim, thank you for your work.

Comment: This time it's my fault for not reading close enough. :) `~/.local/share/nvim/site` is part of `'runtimepath'`, not `~/.local/share/nvim`.  Either `~/.local/share/nvim/site/{autoload,bundle}` or `~/.config/nvim/{autoload,bundle}` can be used.  I'll update the answer.